# Select a field. If it's null, select another

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement

In my user table, there's email and number fields. I have to select the email. But if it is null, select the number. Can I do this in one query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(email, number)
FROM   tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76523/1)
- [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

From Docs,

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Comment: Nice. I was searching something like if-else. I didn't know about this function. Thank you.

Comment: I know. I have just to wait 4 minutes.